# Javascript: how to match multiple variables in one lookup array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lookup

**live example below**
Let's say I want to match city abbreviations with their city names. What is the simplest way to do that? I tried using a lookup, but not sure how to match an array of variables with the lookup array.

So, I want to get the results: `Los Angeles`, `San Francisco`

```js
input1 = "LA";
input2 = null;
input3 = "SF";
result = {
 "LA": "Los Angles",
 "NY": "New York",
 "SF": "San Francisco"
}[input1, input2, input3];

document.write(result);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: do you not want to loop the inputs and access your obj like `let city = myObj[currentInput]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map`. If you want to keep any nulls as undefined:

```js
const input = ["LA", null, "SF"];
const abbreviations = {
 "LA": "Los Angles",
 "NY": "New York",
 "SF": "San Francisco"
};

const result = input.map(e => abbreviations[e]);
console.log(result);
```

Or filter null/false/undefined:

```js
const input = ["LA", null, "SF"];
const abbreviations = {
 "LA": "Los Angles",
 "NY": "New York",
 "SF": "San Francisco"
};

const result = input.map(e => abbreviations[e]).filter(e => e);
console.log(result);
```

Note that your `result` variable name for the lookup object conflicts with the result array, so I adjusted your names a bit.

Comment: surprised why this answer was down-voted?.More surprised when it was deleted.+1

Comment: I'm not the one downvoting. Thanks for this beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than few ways to do this ([map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) / [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) / [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) / `while loop & shift :)`) etc. Here are few examples:

**Note**: I am replacing the `undefined` with `N/A` as well as in the `reduceReplace` function skipping any [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) etc.

```js
var objMap = { "LA": "Los Angles", "NY": "New York", "SF": "San Francisco"}
var match = ['LA', undefined, 'SF']

const mapReplace = (arr) => arr.map(x => !!x ? objMap[x] : 'N/A')
const reduceReplace = (arr) => arr.reduce((r, c) => { !!c ? r.push(objMap[c]) : r; return r }, [])
const shiftReplace = (arr) => {
  var result = []
  while(arr.length > 0) {
    result.push(objMap[arr.shift()])
  }
  return result;
}

console.log('map: ', mapReplace(match)) // This will just replace the strings
console.log('reduce: ', reduceReplace(match)) // This will also skip any undefined/null etc
console.log('shift: ', shiftReplace(match)) // Just for fun
```

The reduce approach here is simply to have one function to get rid of the falsy values it is not needed at all if you want to have the `undefined` in the array since then `map` would go though each element and return the same size array result.

Obviously you can also use `forEach` and other methods to go over the array one element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If I take your example :

You can probably use `const cityKey = Object.keys(result);`, to get only the keys inside your `object`. (The output of this, is an `Array` type)

The second step is to `filter` this array (`cityKey`). And If one iteration match with your condition you can `return true` or `return false`

Please check this fiddle for your more information :  [LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qm0rgbty/2/)

Comment: If you have a better solution, answer this post and downvote, but otherwise if you have no solution why downvote ?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple way:

1) Arrange your inputs as an array
2) Match your array against your table/dictionary/map/lookup

`[input1, input2, input3].forEach(cityCode => console.log(result[cityCode]));`

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` the `keys` and then `reduce` the `main object` based on it.

```js
input1 = "LA";
input2 = null;
input3 = "SF";
var input=[input1,input2,input3];

var data = {
 "LA": "Los Angles",
 "NY": "New York",
 "SF": "San Francisco"
}

var filtered=Object.keys(data)
  .filter(key => input.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key]=data[key];
    return  obj;
  }, {});

console.log(filtered);
console.log(Object.values(filtered));
```